# Convert Java Timestamp in TOD Format (Time of Day) on z/os

Tags: java, zos

As the Search Method "readSearch" of the ZLogstream class needs the Timestamp in TOD format, I've to convert the JAVA Timestamp in TOD (Time of Date) format.

I couldn't find any class (wrapper), which does that for me. Only the getTodClock of the ZUtil class give me the current TOD (Time of Date),but I couldn't convert any timestamp in the right format.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah sure. I tried to get the UnixTimeStamp by using
long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
but this is not the TOD, which is expected the seconds since 1900 and not 1970, as the UnixTimestamp is...

Comment: If you've got unix epoch seconds, can you just add 2208988800 to convert to seconds since 1900? (magic number calculated in JS: `(new Date('1970-01-01T00:00Z') - new Date('1900-01-01T00:00Z')) / 1000`)

Comment: I think it's not so quite easy as it sounds.
I found a solution here how to convert TOD in a Java Timestamp:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817202/tod-clock-time-to-java-util-date-or-milliseconds

But I need the opposite way - form Java Timestamp to TOD. Problem here is that the last three digtis are used IBM intern. Has anybody a solution?

Comment: If you just want to get an instant of now as a TOD value use [ZUtil.getTodClock](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.60_26.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZUtil.html#getTodClock())

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a Rexx procedure:

Tod = (epoc*4096000000)+9048018124800000000

TOD (Time-of-Day in S360, S370, S390 & z/Arch IBM's archs) is a 64bit counter  whose Bit position 31  is incremented every 1.048576 seconds, starting at 1900-01-01.

So, 2**32/1.048576 = 4096000000 = 1 sec.

9048... is the difference between 1900-01-01 and epoch 1970-01-01 in TOD units.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: need more details?

Comment: This looks better. Remember that the better your answers are, the easier they are for other users to understand and the more likely they are to vote them up. :)