# How to convert epoch unix time to TOD clock (STCK)?

Tags: c, assembly, sas, mainframe, zos

Please can you help me to convert epoch Unix time to  TOD clock (STCK) 8 bytes.
e.g :

1. **EPOCH time in Hex = '175BC71AFE2'X**
2. **EPOCH time in Decimal =  1,605,184,368,610**
3. **and I want to convert this decimal to STCK (TOD clock time)?**

Comment: Can you do division with remainder? Not sure if unix time counts leap seconds too, that would complicate things.

Comment: Yes, I can. I am doing with C language

Comment: It's really that my problem, is the remainder,

Comment: I need STCK with the remainder.

Comment: Not sure what STCK is, but I assume TOD means hours-minutes-seconds. You can just use `div`.

Comment: Read here about this type of time: http://www.longpelaexpertise.com.au/toolsTOD.php

Answer (score 1):

The Store Clock Instruction STCK takes the TOD clock and stores it in an 8-byte field.  Bit position 31 is incremented approximately every 1.048576 seconds.  Here is a [link](http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/toolsTOD.php) that provides a way to convert a STCK to a current date.

See this answer to a similar question of converting a current time to a TOD value for comparing timestamps in a LogStream using Rexx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171737/convert-java-timestamp-in-tod-format-time-of-day-on-z-os)

I'm not sure what your application is but also be aware that there is a STCKE instruction that uses an extended format.

Quoted here for convenience

```
This works for me in a Rexx procedure:

Tod = (epoc*4096000000)+9048018124800000000

TOD (Time-of-Day in S360, S370, S390 & z/Arch IBM's archs) is a 
64bit counter whose Bit position 31 is incremented every 1.048576 
seconds, starting at 1900-01-01.

So, 2**32/1.048576 = 4096000000 = 1 sec.

9048... is the difference between 1900-01-01 and epoch 1970-01-01 in TOD units.
```

Refer to the [Principles of Operation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/690450_SA22-7832-03.pdf) for more information on page 7-182 regarding STCK and STCKE formats.

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing what is showed here, but my problem with that is epoch is in seconds and the reminder is truncated when dividing by 1000.

Comment: Two things.  First, what OS. Second, what are you trying to do.  Compare values.  Store them?     Understand the application might help better help you

Comment: 1) Z/OS V2.4 2) its application which monitoring elapsed time between two points of time of API Requesters in Z/OS Connect EE. I need to do difference between two STCK times to get the elapsed time.

Comment: Elapsed time is <seconds.hundreth of seconds>

Comment: Converting a Unix Epoch time to a STCK format will not get you to the seconds.hundreths resolution you are looking for since Epoch is in seconds.  Are you recording the time and doing the comparison or are you using logs / metric data from z/OS Connect?  There are assembler services you can call like STCKCONV that would enable you to convert two STCK times to decimal formats for the comparison.

Comment: Logs metrics data API Requester Interceptor.I am receiving epoch time from the interceptor and I need to convert that to STCK

Comment: 1 questions , what is STCK ,is it seconds unit.,if that the situation i can add the milliseconds to converted STCK.i mean double variable .

Comment: STCK as well as STCKE are

Comment: Sorry for the finger-check. Here comes the full text.     STCK as well as STCKE are not time formats but CPU instructions. They store the current content of the "time of day CPU register", aka the "TOD clock" into a storage area. I suggest you follow the link to the "Principles of Operation" which Hogstrom posted earlier and read chapter "Timing". It explains the TOD format, how it is incremented, and refers to STCK and STCKE as the program interface to get the value.

Comment: I'm a bit confuesed: The title is "How to convert epoch unix time to TOD clock (STCK)?", but a few posts back you wrote "I need to do difference between two STCK times to get the elapsed time.". So you need to calculate the difference between two time values. If you get "UNIX" value, why do you want to convert to TOD format? You can simply substract the two values (and this applies to TOD values as well).

Comment: Because I got two different formats , one in Epoch,the other in STCK, so because of this I need to convert the Epoch to STCK and calculate the difference between of them.